# Convex Optimization, linear program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am new to optimization. 
I have a problem
$Y_k=\sum_{m=1}^M x_{mk} log(1+C_{mk})$

$maximize\sum_{k=1}^K{Y_k} $

subject to: $Y_k \geq b, \forall k $

$\sum_{k=1}^K x_{mk}\leq 1, \forall m $

$ 0 \leq x_{mk} \leq 1, \forall m,k$

```
    .
```

Is this convex optimization problem. 
How can we show it using first order necessary condition or Hessian matrix? 
Or is there any other way to show it?

Comment: Is $C_{mk}$ a variable or a given input?

Comment: It's a variable.

Comment: Then you need to prove whether $x_{mk} log (1+C_{mk})$ is concave...

Comment: This $C_{mk}=g_{mk}/x_{mk}$. The function $x_{mk}log(1+g_{mk}/x_{mk})$ is concave. I proved it. Furthermore summation of a concave function is also concave. All the constraints are linear and affine. I am confused why we call it convex optimization if the objective function is concave. problem (I am sorry for sounding like nonsense to many but I am really confuse )

Comment: Maximizing a concave function is equivalent to minimizing the negative of that concave function, which is convex.

Comment: @ Brain Borchers Thank you so much. Answer with logic. Once again thank you so much.